# How to fix size of combobox ZK when pressed up or down keyboard

Tags: javascript, java, css, zk

I have a problem using combo box zk, i am run it in firefox browser, when i clicked the combo box using mouse it working fine like this :[image: on open with mouse] but when i am pressing Up or Down on keyboard combo item seem sized to 0 : [image: on press key up and down], here is my code of combobox

```
<div>
                                    <combobox width="100%" 
                                              readonly="true"
                                             selectedItem="@bind(vm.tenorSel)" 
                                              value="@load(vm.tenorSel.lovName)"
                                              model="@load(vm.tenor)"
                                              onSelect="@command('cbxTenorChange')">
                                        <template name="model">
                                            <comboitem  value="@bind(each.lovName)"  label="@load(each.lovName)" />
                                        </template>
                                    </combobox>
                                    <label value="@load(vmsgs['tenorSel'])" 
                                           style="color:red"/>
                                </div>
```

Comment: Could you post your code on http://zkfiddle.org/ so we can debug it.

Comment: as for you code sample it seems a little strange to have width 100% in container (div) with few childs. Maybe it will be better to you hlayout instead of div and hlex="1", hflex="min" instead of width attribute.

Comment: i have change div to hlayout but still no effect

Comment: Could you post your code on zkfiddle.org so we can debug it

Comment: i've make a simple combobox in zk fidle and working fine without event onSelect, i think my fault is the code at onSelect event in my view model